# Mysql PDO : get row with "dynamic" fields in query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, row, fetch

I have a query with a dynamic field, how do I access this field without knowing its name?

```
define('FIELD_NAME',"name");
$stmt = $connexion->query('SELECT '.FIELD_NAME.' from mytable);   

while ($rs=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    echo $rs->FIELD_NAME;   // DOESN'T WORK
    echo $rs->name;         // WORK
}
```

Comment: You have a typo at the end of the query. You forgot a closing quote. Adding error checking would have shown that to you.

Comment: Don't use `::FETCH_OBJ`, but fetch a [numeric result array](http://php.net/pdostatement.fetch) and just get the first entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the constant in `{}` to create dynamic variables.

```
echo $rs->{FIELD_NAME};
```

You can see some example from [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

> Curly braces may also be used, to clearly delimit the property name.

Demo: http://3v4l.org/sgvV4

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 3):

There are lot of approaches to this. If it's not important that the variable name match the column_name, you could assign an alias to the expression in the `SELECT` statement

For example:

```
 SELECT whateverexpression AS mycol FROM mytable LIMIT 1;
```

Then, you'd "know" the name of the variable in the object is `$mycol`

```
    echo $rs->mycol;
```

I'm thinking this approach might be good in the more general case, when you're dealing with tables that have column names that were assigned by <strike>syphilitic idiot</strike> developers who had a good reason to

```
CREATE TABLE t (`Hey!$I (can)^name.\my->column Wh@tever` INT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (42);
SELECT `Hey!$I (can)^name.\my->column Wh@tever` FROM t;
```

---

Obviously, there are lots of other approaches, like avoiding `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` and using `PDO::FETCH_NUM` instead. If you want to stick with `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`, I'm thinking assigning an alias would be workable.

Retrieving the metadata from the resultset is an approach I would consider, if `getColumnMeta` wasn't still experimental.

Comment: I didn't know syphilis caused programmers to create columns like that, but I'm actually surprised that's a valid column name haha

Comment: @Mike: References to that column will have to be enclosed in backticks. What I don't know is what PDO::FETCH_OBJ does with a column name like that in the resultset, what the member variable gets named.

Comment: Challenge accepted! `object(stdClass)#4 (1) {
    ["Hey!$I (can)^name.\my->column Wh@tever"]=>
    int(1)
  }`

Comment: So you can access it with `$result->{'Hey!$I (can)^name.\my->column Wh@tever'};`. Yuck!

Comment: @Mike. Nicely, nicely done. Now... I'm tempted to include a nefarious single quote (heh heh) in my next column name...  mmmBWAAA HAAA HAAAAAA cough sputter.

Comment: Yeah, or you could even throw in a backtick. Apparently they're [permitted](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/753) as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
define('FIELD_NAME',"name");
        $stmt = $connexion->query('SELECT '.FIELD_NAME.' from mytable');   

        while ($rs=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
            echo $rs[0];
        }
```

Using this approach, if FIELD_NAME is defined to something like *, you will still be able to get the first column.

Comment: Just noticed that mario already suggested this in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only trying to get a single value from each row, you can use [`PDOStatement::fetchColumn()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

```
define('FIELD_NAME',"name");
$stmt = $connexion->query('SELECT '.FIELD_NAME.' from mytable');
while ($col = $stmt->fetchColumn()) {
    echo $col;
}
```

Also note, you were missing a `'`.